# c++ read image pixels

Tags: c++, image, pixel

I want a c++ Code to read every pixel from an image file. and i want to save the pixels like:
r[]
g[]
b[]

does somebody know how to do this?

Comment: That depends. What kind of image file?

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the format of the image file.  Is it a format which contains raw RGB data (such as uncompressed [TGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truevision_TGA))?  Is it a YUV image?  Is it a compressed image such as JPEG or PNG?

There are already plenty of C++ libraries out there which can read a wide variety of image file formats, and then provide the pixel-level access you require.  Take a look at Adobe's [GIL](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/gil/Generic+Image+Library), or [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/) for example.

Comment: @Paul, added references to some libraries which can do what the OP requires - I think this now qualifies as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are many freely available libraries for reading different image file formats. Since you're using C++ you might want to look at Adobe's [Generic Image Library (GIL)](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/gil/Generic+Image+Library) or even [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/).

Answer (score 1):

This will sort you out, very easy to use and 'low level' image library:
http://easybmp.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Two libraries that I've used that jump to mind are:

- [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)
- [libGD](http://www.libgd.org/)

These libraries can handle a wide variety of image formats, depending on what you need.